# behaving like a hyperlink

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

See this revisions link, https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4315290/1

[image]

the above is just a text, when I hover mouse over the text, its behaving like a hyperlink? Mouse cursor changed to "hand point" as in link but nothing happened on clicked.

Why this behaviour? Is it a bug?

Update:
I made little research

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4315290/2

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4315290/3

Showing **2 of 3** and **3 of 3** respectively, means its behaving like we do **< (previous) ** or **(next) >**  for previous or next revisions. But then **<** **>** missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS file turns the cursor into a pointer here because on the revision *list* (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4315290/revisions)), that number is indeed clickable. In the *single* revision view however it's not, so from the next build on there will be no more pointers there.

Comment: poke! see [my answer below](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260908/1590950) for another possibly related popup that could be added to the list

Comment: @indivisible We have lots of tooltips on the site, I don't see a problem with that. And once the numbers are bigger and get shortened, the values aren't identical (e.g. the tooltip says 1234, but we just display 1.2k). The problem here was just the mouse cursor changing shape.

Answer (score 0):

It is a result of the HTML elements and CSS properties that the page contains.

The mouse pointer is changed with a CSS rule `cursor: pointer;` that is enforced on the `<td>` element containing the revision information element. It is implemented in the `revcell2` CSS class.

The tooltip effect is defined within the HTML in the `title` attribute on the actual `<span>` containing the text:

```
<span title="revision 2">2 of 3</span>
```

Comment: You can, however, have a tooltip without changing the cursor to a hand. Really the cursor shouldn't change to a hand if there's no action available.

Comment: @ChrisF - I guess that's what the OP is hinting at.. I agree though, `pointer` shouldn't  be used if it doesn't actually do what it appears to do.